# angular handling 2 versions of a directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I need to create 2 versions of a directive that will be used for AB testing.
The directive will have the same name, but can be in different modules.
Both directives to be available so it can be turned on/off by an external property.
The question is how do I get it to load the right directive version based on maybe a configuration object on the page at runtime?
e.g.

```
angular.module('component_v1', [])
.directive('myDirective', function () {
...
});

angular.module('component_v2', [])
.directive('myDirective', function () {
...
});
```

HTML

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont have an answer but http://devchat.tv/adventures-in-angular/031-aia-advanced-directives discusses this situation and why it is handled by angular oddly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap to achieve this . like for your case , you can bootstrap the application either with componenet_v1 or component_v2 based on the variable 'someCondition' . like :

```
var someCondition=true; // this will be set true or false based on some condition



 if(someCondition)
{
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['component_v1']);
    });
 }
else
{
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['component_v2']);
});
}
```

and in your html, simply use `<my-directive></my-directive>` and it will call the proper directive based on the module it loads.

You can use any DOM element instead of 'document'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create only one directive:

```js
angular.module('component', [])
.directive('myDirective', function () {

  if($scope.externalProperty==='ver_1') {
    //handle for ver 1.
  } else if($scope.externalProperty==='ver_2') {
    //handle for ver 2.
  }
  ...  
  else {
   //handle for ver n.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I want to avoid this because each of the directives are quite complex and the idea is that once a version has been decided it's just a matter of deleting a folder (and perhaps some configuration) instead of changing actual the directive code.  This would reduce risk and the need for full regression test.